# Debugging with alert

Tags: php, jquery

So, I have the following **php**:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_some_ajax', 'some_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_some_ajax', 'some_ajax' );
function some_ajax()
{   
if (some_condition)
    {
    /*Some function*/   
    }   
}
```

Then **js**:

```
  jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.button', function(e) {     
         jQuery.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : custom.ajax_url,
            data : {'action':'some_ajax'},              
            success : function(data){

                }
         });            
     }
  });
```

So, I want to add some sort of alert for debugging purpose. As you can see, it is an ajax function. I tried to add jQuery alert but no success (or not sure where the alert should show up at).

Can someone show me how to put alerts for debugging purpose?

Thanks

Comment: That is not jquery, that is javascript.  It also won't run until the generated string (which is all echo does) is actually parsed by the client HTML rendering engine.

Comment: Even with Ajax, you can't call a Javascript function from within PHP.  Just echo what you're trying to say with PHP.

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <?php some_ajax() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and your php code

```
function some_ajax()
{
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Something happened');</script>";
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hi. I added js that calls the php function via ajax. Where would I put `console.log()` so that I can get the feedback from the php?

Comment: You would put `console.log()` where ever you need to see results.

Comment: @steveKim Put `console.log(data)` inside your success function if you want to se what's returned from your request